# Does Json.net support more complicated wildcard searches with SelectTokens()?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath, jpath

I know that I can do a wildcard search like this:

```
jObject.SelectTokens("items.*.name");
```

I build the search path at runtime, its not hardcoded. In certain cases, I need to do a search for something a bit more complex like "q*", so that would result in a search path of:

```
jObject.SelectTokens("items.q*.name");
```

Json.net doesn't seem to support that, so in cases like that, I change the search string to "items.*.name" and then use a Where clause with regex to filter down to the ones that match the wildcard, so, the regex might be:

```
^items\.q.*\.name$
```

That's a simple case, of course, but it could be multiple *'s along the path and it could be something like ".*v2.", etc.

If there is some way to do that natively in json.net (or a better way of doing the regex), I can get rid of the regex matching since that is where the profiler is saying an expense is.

Comment: Not sure if it's what you wanted, but you can use the [union operator](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to select multiple specific properties, e.g. `jObject.SelectTokens("items['q1','q2'].name")`.